# I cannot find the table I created in the schema

Tags: mysql

I have a questions when I try to create a table in mysql.
The syntax is below:

```
create table abc as
(select * from 
(select adddate('2010-01-01',t5.i*100000 +t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4,
 (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t5) v 
where selected_date between '2010-01-01' and '2020-12-31');
```

It seems that I create the table successfully, but I cannot find this table in the tables list or even in the schema.

Could someone who has expertise in SQL help me check the syntax?

Comment: you are missing  comm before `selected_date`

Comment: It might be an alias, e.g., `as selected_date`.  I'm afraid I have no idea why `union` statements are being used to collect integers into what look like tables t0 through t5?

Comment: I have created above table successfully

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam Thanks for your notes. Mm My question is that i can create the table successfully by using my syntax, but I cannot find my table in the schema or the table list. So, I cannot view the table or manipulate it. I am new in SQL. Please guide me.

Comment: I have created and able to see it in list, please create a simple table to test db issue